# Attach database with NORECOVERY

Tags: sql-server, backup, database-restore

Is there a way to attach a SQL Server mdf/ldf files such that the database is in Restoring mode and we can restore log backups on top of it.

I have a hardware array snapshot (crash consistent) that contains the mdf/ldf files. I need to attach these files to another SQL Server instance and then do log restores for a point in time recovery(using stopat)

The CREATE DATABASE .. FOR ATTACH command brings the database online. Log restore cannot be done on an online database.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: How are the crash consistent snapshots being taken? If it's through the VDI, the hardware vendor will typically provide a VDI compatible way to do the restore.

Comment: They are not thru VDI. I am a developer exploring options as groundwork for my project. What is the exact relationship between VDI and VSS? Do they have anything in common or are they old-new types. Should a new hardware vendor snapshot implementation even bother about VDI?

Comment: This would be a useful feature for snapshotting on a warm standby SQL server, and be able to attach from a snapshot, and continue to restore with log files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Unfortunately.  Vote for the feature here: 
[DCR - Attach database with NORECOVERY](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/604224)